# How to enable Power Users Group on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

How to enable Power Users Group on Windows Server 2012 ?

as per Microsoft technet :

> By default, members of this group have no more user rights or permissions than a standard user account. The Power Users group in previous versions of Windows was designed to give users specific administrator rights and permissions to perform common system tasks. In this version of Windows, standard user accounts inherently have the ability to perform most common configuration tasks, such as changing time zones. For legacy applications that require the same Power User rights and permissions that were present in previous versions of Windows, **administrators can apply a security template that enables the Power Users group** to assume the same rights and permissions that were present in previous versions of Windows.

[TN Default local groups](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771990.aspx)

so how this could be done, could some one help ?

Comment: have you installed the template

Comment: You want to install this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36991 or create your own group and give the **only** the permission you need to give to the group which is the most secure way to create a power user group

Comment: @Ramhound i have installed the template but how it can help ? how to use it ?

Comment: I will again repeat create a user group with only the permissions that are required.

Answer (score 1):

The Power users group is no longer used [since Windows Vista](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steriley/archive/2008/02/11/plan-now-to-eliminate-power-users-from-your-domains.aspx) and the ACL entries are only there for app compatibility. So don't use them any longer.